# How to find all longest matches of a string from vector

Tags: r, string, text-extraction

I have strings from which I need to extract all matches from a vector using the rebus package.

```
s <- "Heart disease Heart diseases include Blood vessel disease, such as coronary artery disease Heart rhythm problems arrhythmias Heart defects you're born with congenital heart defects Heart valve disease Disease of the heart muscle Heart infection"

symp.rx <- or1(whole_word(c("Heart", "Heart rythm", "Heart valve")))
stri_extract_all_regex(s, symp.rx)
```

running the above code gives me
"Heart" "Heart" "Heart" "Heart" "Heart"

what am I missing? I need also heart rythm, heart valve, etc...

note: The text is actually a column of a large dataframe and the vector (symp.rx) is over 5000 words and I need the output as a simplified vector for each  row of the dataframe (in a second column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the longer pattern first and then include the shorter ones.

```
library(rebus)

symp.rx <- or1(whole_word(c("Heart rythm", "Heart valve", "Heart")))

stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(s, symp.rx)
#[1] "Heart"    "Heart"       "Heart"     "Heart"   "Heart valve" "Heart"
```

Comment: symp.rx <- symp.rx[order(-nchar(symp.rx))]

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah ... adding this line  did it...  but I'm wondering why this happens when extract_all should extract all instances...

Comment: When there is a conflicting pattern match, regex engine will always extract pattern which occurs first in the pattern. See the difference in output of `stringr::str_extract_all('This is the text', 'the|the text')` and `stringr::str_extract_all('This is the text', 'the text|the')`